# Sent request parameters to UploadAction in gwt-upload

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gwtupload

I get [gwt-upload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) working in a GAE application. As [suggested](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwtupload/MNAz7UHXfm4), I implemented a Custom UploadAction to handle the storage of the file in the DataStore. The code goes like this:

```
public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request,
        List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
    logger.info("Starting: DatastoreUploadAction.executeAction");
    String executeAction = super.executeAction(request, sessionFiles);

    for (FileItem uploadedFile : sessionFiles) {            
        Long entityId = new Long(2001); // This is where i wanna use a request parameter
        InputStream imgStream;
        try {
            imgStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
            Blob attachment = new Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(imgStream));
            String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
            appointmentDao.setAppointmentAttachment(entityId, attachment,
                    contentType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to store file", e);
            throw new UploadActionException(e);
        }

    }

    return executeAction;
}
```

As you see, the DAO class requires the "EntityID" to store the uploaded file in the DataStore. Now i'm working with a hard-coded value and it goes fine, but i'd like to have the entityID sent by the client as a request parameter. The widget that does the upload is a MultiUploader:

```
private MultiUploader defaultUploader;
```

Is it posible to the MultiUploader -or any other Widget- to set a request parameter so i can use it in my UploadAction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set it on your client-side code. 
There is method: [`MultiUploader #setServletPath(java.lang.String)`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/googlecode/gwtupload/gwtupload/0.6/gwtupload-0.6-javadoc.jar!/gwtupload/client/MultiUploader.html#setServletPath%28java.lang.String%29), for example:

```
  final MultiUploader u = new MultiUploader();
  ...
  ...
  ...
  u.setServletPath(u.getServletPath() + "?entityId="+myObject.getEntityId());
```

on server side:

```
  String entityId= request.getParameter("entityId");
```

Read this for more information: [Sending additional parameters to the servlet](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/Servlets#Sending_additional_parameters_to_the_servlet)